# Image dependent on link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I want to take out the image div to outside the `a` `href` while keeping the effect it has on it when pressing the link. I tried but once it is not inside the main div anymore the animation does not work.

Note: the JS script is to set a delay to let the image animate then access the link.

https://codepen.io/jinzagon/pen/JjXWzQj

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a style="position:absolute; z-index:999999;"href="http://google.com" class="section">TEST
  <div class="response">
    <img src="https://iphonesoft.fr/images/_082019/fond-ecran-dynamique-macos-wallpaper-club.jpg" />
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
body{
  background-color:black;
}

a {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.section {
  position: absolute;
width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
      transition: 4s ease-out;
}
.response {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 00px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 4s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
.clicked {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation: event 2s;

  
}
.clicked .response {
  
  animation: response 4s;
  
}

@keyframes response {
  0% {} 16% {
    opacity: 1;
    
  }
  32% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.15);
   
  }
  100% {
    
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.section').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $a = $(this).addClass('clicked');
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.assign($a.attr('href'));
    }, 1700);
  });
});
```

Comment: instead of doing $(this).addClass('clicked'); do $('.response').addClass('clicked'); and in your CSS just target the div with class clicked for animations.

Comment: @radlaz Sorry I didn't quite get it.

Comment: @radlaz I modified the code and it's kinda just start playing the animation without even clicking the link.

Comment: I miss read some of your code.. sorry forget about that. Can you specify what you mean when you say you want to "take out the image div to outside the a href". Do you mean to appear to be outside the a tag or actually outside the a tag? I'm confused on what you want.

Comment: @radlaz Actually outside the a tag. I want the link alone, the image alone, but the animation of the image to be enabled after clicking the link just as it is now.

Comment: @radlaz I'm getting now error when I'm trying to access the ` a href ` " Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.  "  . I already have .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am still am not sure if you are taking the div outside the a tag with JavaScript or you just manually want to hard code it like that. I'll assume the latter

```
<a style="position:absolute; z-index:999999;"href="http://google.com" class="section">TEST
</a>

<div class="response">
    <img src="https://iphonesoft.fr/images/_082019/fond-ecran-dynamique-macos-wallpaper-club.jpg" />
</div>
```

and for your JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.section').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $responsiveDiv = $('.response')
     $responsiveDiv.addClass('clicked'); // Instead of adding clicked to a tag  add class clicked directly to responsive div
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.assign($responsiveDiv.attr('href'));
    }, 1700);
  });
});
```

and for your CSS

```
body{
  background-color:black;
}

a {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.section {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 4s ease-out;
}
.response {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 00px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 4s ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
.clicked {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation: event 2s;

  
}
.clicked { /* Changed */ 
  
  animation: response 4s;
  
}

@keyframes response {
  0% {} 16% {
    opacity: 1;
    
  }
  32% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.15);
   
  }
  100% {
    
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You got the HTML right, but the animation is not working unfortunately.

Comment: I used the wrong formatting for the comment on css which caused it not to work. It should work now I tested it on code pen. Honest mistake I'm really tired today

Comment: Don't worry. Thank you so so much for the reply this is exactly what I had in mind. Can you elaborae what did you do in css ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a `data-` attribute? That may be the easiest approach to this problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.response img').click(function(e) {
    var $a = $(this).addClass('clicked');
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.assign($a.attr('data-href'));
    }, 1700);
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color:black;
}

a {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.response {
  position: absolute;
width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
      transition: 4s ease-out;
}
.clicked {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation: event 2s;
  animation: response 4s;
}

@keyframes response {
  0% {} 16% {
    opacity: 1;
    
  }
  32% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.15);
   
  }
  100% {
    
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="response">
    <img src="https://iphonesoft.fr/images/_082019/fond-ecran-dynamique-macos-wallpaper-club.jpg" data-href="http://google.com" />
</div>
```

You may now move the `a` anywhere you like if you still need it.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but it didn't work. You may look the answer above.

Comment: I must have mis-understand what you are trying to acheive. But the snippet did exactly what I though you wanted. Congrats on finding an answer that works :)

Comment: My bad man. With data-href the mouse didn't change so I thought the link was not working.

Comment: Just glad I could add my own quota